# Spring with Neo4j, GraphRepository<?> vs handmade interface

Tags: spring, neo4j, repository-pattern, spring-data-neo4j

I found out that there is an interface called GraphRepository. I have a repository for users implementing a homemade interface that does its job, but I was wondering, shouldn't I implement GraphRepository instead ? Even if it will be quite long to implement and some methods will be useless, I think it is a standard and I already re-coded a lot of methods that are defined in this interface.

So should I write "YAGNI" code or not respect the standard ?
What is your advice ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you don't need to actually implement GraphRepository but extend it.  the principals of `Spring-Data` is that all the boiler-plate CRUD code is taken care of (by proxying at startup time) so all you have to do is create an interface for your specific entity extending GraphRepository and then add only specific methods that you require.

for example; if i have an entity `CustomerNode`, to create standard CRUD methods, i can create a new interface `CustomerNodeRepository extends GraphRepository<CustomerNode,Long>`.  all the methods from `GraphRepository` (e.g. save, findAll, findOne, delete, deleteAll, etc.) are now accessible from `CustomerNodeRepository` and implemented by Spring-Data-Neo4J without having to write a single line of implementation code.

the pattern now allows you to work on your specific repository code (e.g. findByNameAndDateOfBirth) rather than the simple CRUD stuff.

Spring-Data package is very useful for repository interaction.  it can reduce huge amounts of code (have seen 80%+ reduction in code lines) and would highly recommend using it

edit: implementing custom execution

if you want to add your own custom behavior to a Repository method, you create the concept of merging interfaces and custom implementation.  for example, lets say i want to create a method called `findCustomerNodeBySomeStrangeCriteria` and to do this, i actually want to link off to a relational database to perform the function.

first we define a separate, standalone interface that *only* includes our 'extra' method.

```
public interface CustomCustomerNodeRepository {
   List<CustomerNode> findCustomerNodeBySomeStrangeCriteria(Object strangeCriteria);
}
```

next we update our normal interface to extend not only GraphRepository, but our new custom one too

```
public interface CustomerNodeRepository extends GraphRepository<CustomerNode,Long>, CustomCustomerNodeRepository {

}
```

the last piece, is to actually implement our `findCustomerNodeBySomeStrangeCriteria` method

```
public class CustomerNodeRepositoryImpl implements CustomCustomerNodeRepository {

   public List<CustomerNode> findCustomerNodeBySomeStrangeCriteria(Object criteria) {
    //implementation code
}

}
```

so, there's a couple of points to note;

- we create a *separate* interface to define any custom methods that have custom implementations  (as distinct from Spring-Data compatible "findBy..." methods)
- our CustomerNodeRepository interface (our 'main' interface) extends both the GraphRepository *and* our 'custom' one
- we implement *only* the 'custom' method in a class that implements *only* the custom interface
- the 'custom' implementation class must (by default) be called our 'main' interface `Impl` to be picked up by Spring Data  (so in this case `CustomNodeRepositoryImpl`)

under the covers, Spring Data delivers a proxy implementation of `CustomerNodeRepository` as a merge of the auto-built `GraphRepository` and our class implementing `CustomCustomerNodeRepository`.  the reason for the name of the class is to allow Spring Data to pick it up easily/successfully (this *can* be overwritten so it doesn't look for *Impl)

Comment: There's something that I don't get, I created an interface iUserRepository extending GraphRepository<User> and a class Neo4jUserRepository implementing iUserRepository, but my IDE (IntelliJ) forces me to override all methods of GraphRepository (because they are abstracts), where am I wrong ?

Comment: the idea of Spring Data is that you don't actually implement the GraphRepository interface (either your extension or any other derivatives).  there is a pattern for creating custom executions within the pattern and i can expand the answer to demonstrate if you like

Comment: I would like. I found multiple examples on how it works, but I don't understand how it can compile if we do not implement abstract methods.

Comment: where are the abstract methods declared?  in your custom or `GraphRepository`?

Comment: Thanks for this precision but the point is that in your case CustomNodeRepositoryImpl implements CustomNodeRepository (which expands GraphRepository) so knowing that GrahpReposiroty methods are abstract, my code won't compile because I didn't override GraphRepository methods in CustomNodeRepositoryImpl.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment. After verification GraphRepository is an interface so there is no abstract methods in it, my wrong.
However, my problem is still the same, Intellij forces me to override many methods when I want to implement an interface that extends GraphRepository.
A problem of dependency maybe ?

Comment: the trick is in which interface the custom class implements; it needs to implement `CustomCustomerNodeRepository` *only*.  and `CustomCustomerNodeRepository` *should not* extend GraphRepository.  Spring Data will merge the two classes later and inject into your `CustomerNodeRepository` bindings