# "No property found for type" combining repositories spring-data-neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, repository-pattern, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using `spring-data-neo4j` and I'm trying to combine repositories to be able to use custom ones. I think I've followed correctly the nomenclature conventions specified in [20.8.7 Creating repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/3.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/programming-model.html) and other SO questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772700/spring-with-neo4j-graphrepository-vs-handmade-interface).

Anyway, I'm doing something wrong because I'm getting this

**exception message**

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property someCriteria found for type User!
```

**User entity**

```
@NodeEntity
public class User {

   @GraphId
   private Long nodeId;
   @Indexed
   String mail;
   ...
}
```

**Repositories** (all in the same package)

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User>, UserRepositoryCustom {
   User findByMail(String mail);
}

public interface UserRepositoryCustom {
  String findBySomeCriteria(String criteria);
}

public class UserRespositoryImpl implements UserRepositoryCustom {
   @Override
   public String findBySomeCriteria(String criteria) {
      return "result";
   }
}
```

**services**

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
   @Autowired
   UserRepository userRepository;
}
```

**Neo4j configuration**

```
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase">
      ...
</bean>
<neo4j:repositories base-package="com.mypackage.api.user.repository"/>
<bean id="userService" class="com.mypackage.api.user.service.UserServiceImpl"/>
```

Comment: Does the package `com.mypackage.api.user.repository` contain both interfaces and the Impl class?

Comment: Thanks for comment. Yes, all of them are in the same package. I put it in the OP but was removed after edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it has been just a stupid `spelling` mistake.

Need change `UserRespositoryImpl` per `UserRepositoryImpl` (without '**s**': note UserRe**s**positoryImpl).

Anyway, I've been struggling with custom repository combination in `spring-data-neo4j` and I think it can be a bit confusing. Also I think there are very few good examples online... So, finally I've decided to create a sample project on `GitHub`, with a basic example showing how we can do that.

Hope it help other people in the future.

See on GitHub: [neo4jCustomRepository](https://github.com/troig/neo4jCustomRepository)